# Linq average, parameter function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {  
    @Html.ActionLink(item.RATES.Average(item => item.rate)), "ShowRates", "Track", new { track_nr = @item.TRACK_NR, album_id=@item.ALBUM_ID}, null)
 <br>
}
```

I am trying to show the average of RATES, RATES is a table in my database that consists of integers in collumn rate. Visual studio is telling me that I have to give a function as parameter. But I have no Idea how to create that function?

Comment: I think the problem might be that you have an extra close paren in there (after "item.rate)").  Take that away, and I don't see any problem with this code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these functions to the View will make it look ugly, I would rather add this as aproperty of my model and do this calculation in my controller before sending this data to the view.

```
public class AlbumViewModel
{
  public int ALBUM_ID { set;get;}
  public string TRACK_NR { set;get;}
  public decimal AVERAGE_RATE{ set;get;}

}
```

Your Action method

```
public ActionResult GetAlbums()
{
   var albums=rep.GetAlbmums();
   foreach(var album in albums)
   {
       album.AVERAGE_RATE=album.Rates.Average();
   }
   return View(albums);    
}
```

And in my **Clean View,**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{  
   @Html.ActionLink(item.AVERAGE_RATE, "ShowRates", "Track", new { track_nr = @item.TRACK_NR, album_id=@item.ALBUM_ID}, null)    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks much cleaner. But I have still the problem that I have to put a Func<> as parameter.
How can I create that func?

Comment: @user1408786 what func ? provide more realistic details

Comment: .Average(<Rates, decimal?> selector) (+9 overloads)

Comment: Solution: track.RATES.AsQueryable().Average(s => (decimal)s.rate)